'branches-ignore' ignoring all branches with workflow_run trigger?
I have a workflow which is using a workflow_run trigger to run a privileged action. I'd like it to only run on PRs, so I've used a branches-ignore filter. This stops the action from running on main-branch builds, but it also stops it running for any PRs.
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ "Gatsby Publish" ]
    types:
      - completed
    branches-ignore:
      - 'main'

The docs are quite specific that the branch here refers to the branch of the triggering workflow:

When using the workflow_run event, you can specify what branches the triggering workflow must run on in order to trigger your workflow.

What am I doing wrong?

Is the behavior the same using the branches: - '!main' filter instead?

It is, yes. I also tried branches: - '*' with various wildcards, just for diagnostics, and there the behaviour was a bit more non-deterministic; it seemed like some PRs were run and some weren't, which was extra-puzzling.

One extra wrinkle is that while I couldn't tell for sure, it seemed like perhaps dependabot PRs were getting previews, but my personal PRs were not getting previews.

It doesn't seem to work as the documentation is stating. Thinking of a workaround, an option could be to use the data from the triggering workflow to check the branch to perform the operation or not if a condition is met. The trade-off is that the workflow_run will always be triggered, but the operation it performs only will be done according to the condition (prevent the action from running on main-branch builds)

I think you may be right. I'm doing that now, but I don't like the clutter of skipped workflows. Although at least it's just clutter, not workflow failure and implementation chaos.

It's started working now, so I wonder if it was a temporary github bug.
